# URL not passing argument to method

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

Here is my RouteConfig:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Edit",
        url: "{sub_num}/Edit",
        defaults: new { controller = "Projects", action = "Create" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Projects", action = "Clear", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

My Create method in my ProjectsController has one argument, `int? sub_num`. When I try to go to `http://localhost:64692/30000032739/Edit`, the method returns a 400 Bad Request, which is the result of a null sub_num argument. I have set a breakpoint to check this, and sub_num is indeed null when the method gets called. What could be causing this?

Comment: `30000032739 > int.MaxValue == true`

Comment: To echo haim770, try switching to `long?` instead of `int?`, or if this value doesn't mean anything numerically, just use a `string`.

Comment: @haim770 You're right. I just made it a string for now and it worked great. Want to answer the question and I'll accept the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, *30000032739* is greater than `Int32.MaxValue` hence the model binder fails to bind it to your `int? sub_num` parameter.

If you're really expecting such numeric values, you better opt for `long?` instead. If it's just an arbitrary sequence of digits you're passing, use `string`, obviously.

See [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)